# EntityManager is null in Spring MVC controller

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC project with Hibernate dependencies:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>5.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager instead of hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
<version>5.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- optional -->

<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-osgi</artifactId>
<version>5.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
<version>5.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
<version>5.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-proxool</artifactId>
<version>5.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-infinispan</artifactId>
<version>5.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
<version>5.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my simple controller:

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Transactional
@RequestMapping("/home")
public String goHome(){
    System.out.println(em);
    return "home";
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

 <beans>

 <bean id="myEmf"                                                                  
 class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
 <property name="dataSource" ref="someDataSource"/>
 <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
 <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.
              InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
 </property>
 </bean>
```

Im not sure what should I put here:

```
 <property name="dataSource" ref="someDataSource"/>
```

What is the dataSource reference in case of hibernate?
This piece of configuration come from [spring dokumentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html)

Comment: Can you make sure that you did not NEW this class instance? This is so often the mistake that is worth asking.

Comment: could you show the context file? do you initialize the entitymanager bean?

Comment: @NawaMan - this is all I have, just this single controller class.

Comment: as there is nothing in the application context (i guess that you also do not use annotation configuration), you need to configure the bean, otherwise they will not be initialized

Comment: I think in the applicationContext xml you will have to add component scan package of the controller. Add <context:component-scan base-package="your .package.for.controller" />

Answer (score 0):

Try this application context xml:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

     <beans>

    <context:component-scan base-package="your.package.for.controller" />

 <bean id="myEmf"                                                                  
     class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="someDataSource"/>
     <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
     <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.
                  InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
     </property>
     </bean>
```

Comment: @jarosik the only diff is this line in the xml:  <context:component-scan base-package="your.package.for.controller" />

Answer (score 0):

Look at the spring config below (dataSource, component-scan directories and hibernate properties should be adjusted to your needs):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"

   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

// will enable jpa repositories if you use one
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.xyz.database.repository"/>
// allow usage of transactional annotation
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
//scans for spring components
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz"/>
// dataSource creates connection to database
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
</bean>

// create entity manager 
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.xyz"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">10000</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">100</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>

// create transaction manager 
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        </bean>
</beans>
```

after that you can use:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

Comment: I have "The prefix *  for element * is not bound with all three:     <jpa:repositories base-package="com.xyz.database.repository"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com."/>

Comment: oh, i forgot the you should also add the schemaLocation to the beans - i updated the post

Comment: error: cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'beans' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.